# How to give the user some time to click an element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this code;

```
var lastTdI;
var lastTdJ;
function createTable() {
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var tr1 = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            var td1 = document.createElement("td");
            td1.setAttribute("id", "td" + i + j)
            td1.addEventListener("click", ((a, b) => { return function () { lastTdI = a; lastTdJ = b; middleSquare(a, b); } })(i, j));
        }
        tbl.appendChild(tr1);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(tbl);
}

function middleSquare(i , j) {
    while (!(i == 1 && j == 1)) {
        alert('Invalid square. Please press on the middle square.');
        //Here do I want to give the user some time to press on a different one in order to change lastTdI and lastTdJ
        i = lastTdI;
        j = lastTdJ;
       
    }
    alert("Fantastic! you have pressed on the middle square.")
}
```

My focus here lies in the `middleSquare()` function. I have a loop that is aimed to alert "invalid square" as long as the square that was pressed on isn't valid. But my problem arises here: After alerting "Invalid move", I wish to let the user time to press on a different square, so that the global variables `lastTdI` and `lastTdJ` will change accordingly. After these change, the loop condition can be checked again and the process will continue as long as the pressed `td` isn't valid. With this code, the "invalid move" is alerted in an infinite loop since i and j are not changed. May someone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function()
        { 
          i = lastTdI; 
          j = lastTdJ;
        }, 2000);
```

Try using setTimeout function. 2000 is a timeout. [2000 Milliseconds = 2 Seconds]

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried using setTimeout, but it doesn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the while loop from the middleSquare function and use if statement instead. The middleSquare function runs everytime the user clicks a cell. So, it enough to show success message if middle square is clicked and invalid message if other squares are clicked.

```
function middleSquare(i, j) {
    if (!(i == 1 && j == 1)) {
        alert("Invalid square. Please press on the middle square.");
        //Here do I want to give the user some time to press on a different one in order to change lastTdI and lastTdJ
        i = lastTdI;
        j = lastTdJ;
    } else {
        alert("Fantastic! you have pressed on the middle square.");
    }
}
```

```js
var lastTdI;
var lastTdJ;
function createTable() {
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var tr1 = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            var td1 = document.createElement("td");
            td1.setAttribute("id", "td" + i + j);
            td1.addEventListener(
                "click",
                ((a, b) => {
                    return function () {
                        lastTdI = a;
                        lastTdJ = b;
                        middleSquare(a, b);
                    };
                })(i, j)
            );
            tr1.appendChild(td1);
        }
        tbl.appendChild(tr1);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(tbl);
}

function middleSquare(i, j) {
    if (!(i == 1 && j == 1)) {
        alert("Invalid square. Please press on the middle square.");
        //Here do I want to give the user some time to press on a different one in order to change lastTdI and lastTdJ
        i = lastTdI;
        j = lastTdJ;
    } else {
        alert("Fantastic! you have pressed on the middle square.");
    }
}

createTable();
```

```css
td {
    background: gray;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried to do that with an `if` statement but it didn't work' that's why I tried the loop. I probably had a little mistake somewhere then. Thanks!